# Street adresses with specific number, combinations and permutations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> How many different 5-digit street addresses can have the digits 4, 7,
>   3, 4, and 8?

The answer (according to the website where I foung this question) is $$\frac{5!}{
2!} = 60$$

Why do I have to divide by $2!$ ?

Comment: Because there are two 4 and their order does not count.

Comment: @Augustin Oh, I didn't see the second 4. I understand now

Comment: See [Multinomial Coefficients on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients).  This is essentially the multinomial coefficient $\binom{5}{2,1,1,1} = \frac{5!}{2!1!1!1!}=60$